# Save changes in ms access file

Tags: powershell, ms-access, scripting

```
$path = “C:\path\myfile.mdb”
$cn = new-object -comobject ADODB.Connection
$rs = new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset
```

Opening connection to the Database

```
$cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$path;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypassword;")
```

Query that i want to edit

```
$query = "Select Taxes from TaxBands"
$rs.Open($query, $cn)
$data = $rs.GetRows()
```

Updating and multiplying the values in the Taxes column

```
foreach ($row in $data)
{

$row= $row*2    
write-host $row
}
```

Question: How to save and update the new values in the table TaxBands from $row and close the mdb file.

Answer (score 2):

Update values with the `fields` and `value`: `$recordSet.Fields.Item("lastName").value`

And close the objects with `.close()`: `$cn.Close()` and `$rs.Close()`